# NuxtJs deploying issue on plesk server

Tags: node.js, deployment, nuxt.js, plesk

I host a domain on plesk server. It contain `Nodejs V 12.4.0`, I am not using anything like express or so.. I Just create nuxt app using `create-nuxt-app` in my pc using `NodeJs V. 16`, then run command `npm run build`, Then after I uploaded the files/folder(**.nuxt, nuxt.config.js, static and package.json**) on server to folder **httpdoc/merostatus.com/(uploaded all files/folder here)**.

**Setting on Nodejs in server:**

```
Document Root : /httpdocs/merostatus.com/static    
Application Mode : production  
Application URL : http://merostatus.com
Application Root : /httpdocs/merostatus.com  
Application Startup File : node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js
```

After this setting I click on **NPM install** button on Plesk and **Restart App**

But the output is not as desired. It is searching for pages folder, When I point Application Startup File to **.nuxt/server.js** It doesn't found vue instance.

My server is on live just now for addressing issue
https://merostatus.com

Comment: @kissu Thankyou for your reply and help. Plesk Server is totally mesh. It only support npm V12 till today. I will post solution in answer section.

Comment: You mean Node.js v12?

Comment: Indeed, it looks dated a bit: https://ext.plesk.com/packages/1e47ed49-bca9-46d6-8828-7d3c42a2f21b-nodejs#!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am currently using Plesk VPS server with OS Ubuntu 20.04

I solved the issue by making change in following ways

**Step 1:** Added nuxt-start module : `npm install --save nuxt-start`

**Step 2:** Build the project : `npm run build`

**Step 3:** Upload project to server including all dependencies (Whole project not only .nuxt)

**Step 4: Changing Setting on Nodejs in server:**

```
Document Root: /httpdocs    
Application Mode: production  
Application URL: http://merostatus.com
Application Root: /httpdocs  
Application Startup File: node_modules/nuxt-start/bin/nuxt-start.js
```

Comment: I'm also having difficulty hosting my nuxt.js app on plesk. However, this provided method does not solve my problem. If I leave Document Root: /httpdocs I just get the default plesk index page fetched. I tried changing this to /httpdocs/.nuxt and /httpdocs/.nuxt/dist which then provides a different error (generic nuxt 500 error). What did you do with the default index.html generated by plesk?

Answer (score 0):

If you do have `target: server` (default), you indeed need to `npm run build`. The usual process is going through either `npm run build` or `npm run generate` (if `target: static`).

Then, uploading **only** your `dist` directory is enough. No need for any other files. Then, running `npm run start` (some platforms do this for you).

I'm not sure about your Plesk server configuration but you can try to build your app and drop the dist directory at Netlify, at least to see if it builds there: https://app.netlify.com/drop

Then, if you achieve this, we could look for Plesk.